# Error: The await expression can only be used in an async function. Try marking the function body with either 'async' or 'async*'

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, async-await, future

```
class Wrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final user = Provider.of<User>(context);
    DocumentSnapshot snapShot = await Firestore.instance.collection('members').document(user.uid).get(); //re

    //defining the user id
    List<String> hr = [
      "4xldjjaJKBOppV0ioZLaIekVNdr1",  //shreya shreya.21810101@viit.ac.in
      "20D18eFrsnRNmbtVnnvq8U0ZW1s2"   //pranav pranav.21810339@viit.ac.in
    ];
    List<String> doc = [
      "3DoGWLpamEVwXyT57hCyybkGIkc2",  //harsha harsha.21810512@viit.ac.in
      "YBHsJC5W6IYa1qfdIaXAwbvKKOG2",  //saampatii saampatii.21810826@viit.ac.in
    ];
    List<String> gs = [
      "5QCDzv1YjQhQdLORJ7CthfATeHt1"   //digu digvijay.21810245@viit.ac.in
    ];


    if(user == null){
      return Authenticate();
    }else if(snapShot == null || !snapShot.exists){return MemberData();}
    else{
      if(user.uid == hr[0]){return Hr();}
      else if(user.uid == hr[1]){return Hr();}
      else if(user.uid == doc[0]){return Doc();}
      else if(user.uid == doc[1]){return Doc();}
      else if(user.uid == gs[0]){return Gs();}
      else{return Home();}
    }
  }
}
```

What can I do to remove the error?

There I tried checking if the document with that uid is stored or not in my firestore. Is there any other way without getting an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use await, you have to make your function async :

```
Future<Widget> getData(user) async {
  DocumentSnapshot snapShot = await Firestore.instance.collection('members')
                                                      .document(user.uid).get();
  //defining the user id
    List<String> hr = [
      "4xldjjaJKBOppV0ioZLaIekVNdr1",  //shreya shreya.21810101@viit.ac.in
      "20D18eFrsnRNmbtVnnvq8U0ZW1s2"   //pranav pranav.21810339@viit.ac.in
    ];
    List<String> doc = [
      "3DoGWLpamEVwXyT57hCyybkGIkc2",  //harsha harsha.21810512@viit.ac.in
      "YBHsJC5W6IYa1qfdIaXAwbvKKOG2",  //saampatii saampatii.21810826@viit.ac.in
    ];
    List<String> gs = [
      "5QCDzv1YjQhQdLORJ7CthfATeHt1"   //digu digvijay.21810245@viit.ac.in
    ];


    if(user == null){
      return Authenticate();
    }else if(snapShot == null || !snapShot.exists){return MemberData();}
    else{
      if(user.uid == hr[0]){return Hr();}
      else if(user.uid == hr[1]){return Hr();}
      else if(user.uid == doc[0]){return Doc();}
      else if(user.uid == doc[1]){return Doc();}
      else if(user.uid == gs[0]){return Gs();}
      return Home();
    }

}
```

Comment: Doing this another error occurred:
This function has a return type of 'Widget', but doesn't end with a return statement.
Try adding a return statement, or changing the return type to 'void'.

Comment: change `Future` to `Future<Widget>`. that shud fix. and return the output of that function call.

Comment: This is not working, can you suggest some other solution.

Comment: Error: This function has a return type of 'Widget', but doesn't end with a return statement.
Try adding a return statement, or changing the return type to 'void'.

Error: The value of the local variable 'user' isn't used.
Try removing the variable, or using it.

Error: The declaration 'getData' isn't referenced.
Try removing the declaration of 'getData'.

Comment: Will modify the code.. changes:- in else part of code remove else and just return. That shud fix it.